# MediaWiki 1.36 internal error: intl required

Tags: php, xampp, mediawiki, intl

It says I require the PHP component intl, which is already installed in my XAMPP directory. Also, I have gotten rid of the semicolon preceding it in the php.ini file, and have no idea how to solve this problem. I'd appreciate it if someone had the answer to this question, thanks.

Comment: Run a page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see if it's activated. Did you restart your server after activating it?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by 'run a page with'? Just trying to clarify.

Comment: Create a `.php` page on your local server with [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) as sole content and call/access it in your browser

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. I'm a total amateur.